# Firestore creating a day total for data entries

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am new to Firestore and working with a Swift project. My aim is to have an insert of data, which the user will insert.

However I want to be able to achieve a day total for each day I enter a new value and then update this value every time I insert a new entry. Would this be able to be done through firebase functions or will I require another route which is less expensive to achieve this. Sorry if this doesn't make sense I will try to provide some samples of what I am trying to achieve:

So for instance I will be making an entry which will follow this data format in JSON.

```
{
   [userId] : [{ 
        trackingData:[
             { [random id]: { value: 15 }, timestamp: 22 Feb 2022 },
             { [random id]: { value: 10 }, timestamp: 22 Feb 2022  },
        ]
   }]
}
```

My question is basically is there a way to have calculate the total day value of the tracking data per day. Using Firestore.

Edit...

The structure is quite simple as shown above when a user enters a record its saved on to its user id as reference. Then placed in its own trackingData collection. Where the results are then saved in a form of an array, where each entry is a single object.

Comment: Could you please share your Firebase structure?

To achieve your goal, you could use [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that fire on when inserting a new value with the [`onCreate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder#oncreate) method and updating (incrementing) a document with the new value. Since I don’t know how your database is structured, this would be my advice.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a sample document and then explain what refers to a "new entry" and "day total". It'll be much clearer that way imo.

Comment: Yeah a new entry would be a user entering a value of a form of an int. This value will also have a dataTime attached. The idea is to have some sort of document/collection attached or separate that is used to calculate the total values added per day @Dharmaraj

Comment: That's really pretty simple but do you want to have the client do the calculation or have it done in the cloud. e.g. when data is written to Firebase, it can trigger an event on your device that could update the total for that day. OR you could have a cloud function that's triggered when data is written and calculate the total OR you you could set up a CRON job ([Cloud Scheduler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)) to fire at 11:59:59 each day and do the calculation The question really needs more details to be answerable.

Comment: @Jay I guess the best solution for this would be to have Cloud function which triggers on data written or deletion to calculate the total. So potentially I could retrieve a weekly figure/ day by day sum. 

For myself I just wonder whats the best solution and where I guess this data should lie, would it be best to place this in its own collection/data set, include within the data structure presented? Would you be able to add a sample answer?

Comment: I am not sure an answer can be provided at this point; cloud functions could be initiated from the client by writing data or could be initiated automatically with Cloud Schedular. Either way, the data could be massaged in any number of ways - probably the simplest is to have another collection with daily totals stored as documents each with a timestamp. Then you could pull data for a day, or a date range to get week, month, yearly totals. Writing that cloud function will be up to you but after you attempt it and get stuck, post your code and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is understood from the question is that you have a simple JSON for each user. You are tracking user activity in this JSON under the field trackingData. This trackingData Array is appended one element of each user activity event, and this event has some event data and timestamp attached to it.
Now, you want to count user activities/day. IMO, The question is missing a key detail about your use case that is "When do you want to update this count (aka SLA)?"

1. As soon as the event is registered?
   A cloud function will be the most suitable option here, Just listen for updated documents and trigger the function to upsert this particular day's count by one. This is expensive as you are going to read and update the same document every single time a user event occurs.
2. End of the day?
   Run a cron job on or after 23:59:59 and calculate the last day's count for each user. You are going to read and update the aggregate document only once a day.
3. Some other time?
   Same as the end of day one but the cron schedule will be different. You will further optimize reads/updates to your SLA.

DO NOT RELY on the client to do this calculation, because:

1. If you are sending an event and count update in the same request, it is an unnecessary load and it will fail if one of those two actions fails.
2. If you are sending two independent requests there will be chances of inconsistency if one of those two will fail.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that would avoid using cloud functions is to just create a collection called "DailyTotals" whose documents would be the daily totals each day.

Then all you have to do is any time a user inserts a new value, just fetch the daily total for that day, add the latest value, then update Firebase. It would cost you an extra read and write, but it would save you from having to mess with cloud functions.